# How to implement ODBC ConfigDriver function with ODBC_REMOVE_DRIVER ( Setup DLL API Reference)

Tags: c++, sql, visual-c++, odbc

I want to implement ODBC driver setup DLL API.
How to implement ConfigDriver function with ODBC_REMOVE_DRIVER option?
I have called SQLRemoveDriver api but it recursively calls ConfigDriver api.
What is the correct way to implement ConfigDriver function with ODBC_REMOVE_DRIVER option